# How can I make a Debian OpenERP package, or reverse-engineer the existing packages?

Tags: debian, odoo

I'd like to build my own Debian package similar to the ones available from http://nightly.openerp.com/, but from my own branch. I see that openobject-server has a debian/ directory, but that doesn't seem to be that simple:

```
~/openobject-server$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
changing mode of /Network/Servers/xserve.macprofessionals.lan/Volumes/Data/Users/pfrost/openobject-server/7.0/debian/openerp/usr/bin/openerp-server to 755
   dh_install
   dh_installdocs
   dh_installchangelogs
install: omitting directory `./history'
dh_installchangelogs: install -o 0 -g 0 -p -m644 ./history debian/openerp/usr/share/doc/openerp/changelog returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

If I delete ./history, then I can get a package to build, and I assume there's a better way to tell dh_installchangelogs where the real changelog is, so that ./history/ doesn't confuse it.

Even so, packaging like this doesn't include the openobject-addons and openerp-web projects, which aren't debianized, but the openerp.com nightly builds do include. Is there an easier way to reproduce that packaging, or do I simply have to repackage everything from scratch?

**Edit:**

Since no one seems to know how OpenERP is building their packages (I suspect it's not public), are there any ideas on how I can extract the useful packaging bits from the binary packages provided and re-use them in my own? The few package disassembly instructions I've found involve only source packages.

Comment: Try installing `fakeroot` and adding `-rfakeroot` to the command line?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this through bzr-builder, which has problems of its own. See [How can several branches be nested in the same directory in a bzr-builder recipe?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235370/how-can-several-branches-be-nested-in-the-same-directory-in-a-bzr-builder-recipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that OpenERP SA uses for the nightly builds is on launchpad as part of the [openerp-tools](http://launchpad.net/openerp-tools) package. Specifically, here is [the apparent relevant file for 7.0](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp-dev/openerp-tools/trunk/view/head:/packaging70/package70.py). It does effectively this:

```
bzr export lp:~openerp/openobject-server/7.0 server
bzr export lp:~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0 addons
bzr export lp:~openerp/openerp-web/7.0 web
mv addons/* server/openerp/addons/
mv web/addons/* server/openerp/addons
cd server
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Thanks to Antony Lesuisse for providing this information in [this useful mailing list post](https://lists.launchpad.net/openerp-community/msg01917.html).

I've found a number of fixes to the packaging necessary for a propper build. I've [fixed the build dependencies](https://code.launchpad.net/~bitglue/openobject-server/fix-debian-builddeps) so that the package will build in a clean environment, like pbuilder. I also [incorporated the fix suggested by Flimzy](https://code.launchpad.net/~bitglue/openobject-server/fix-dh_installchangelogs). Further, I [addressed a number of lintian warnings](https://code.launchpad.net/~bitglue/openobject-addons/fix-unexecutable-files). I also developed packaging for [openobject-server](https://code.launchpad.net/~bitglue/openobject-server/packaging), [openobject-addons](https://code.launchpad.net/~bitglue/openobject-addons/packaging), and [openerp-web](https://code.launchpad.net/~bitglue/openerp-web/packaging) to be packaged separately, though I'd consider this packaging very kludgy, reflecting my very basic knowledge. Improvements welcome.

All of these changes, plus some functionality tweaks I've made for my local version are incorporated into [my recipes on launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~bitglue/+recipes) and [built in this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bitglue/+archive/openerp).

Answer (score 1):

According to the `dh_installchangelogs` man page, you can use the `-X` or `--exclude` flag to exclude upstream changelogs:

> **-X**item, **--exclude**=item
>             Exclude upstream changelog files that contain item anywhere in their filename from being installed.

If that's really the only problem with your build, just add that to the `dh_insallchangelogs` line in `debian/rules`:

> ```
>     dh_installchangelogs -X./history
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. However it doesn't help me to reproduce all the functionality that's in the official OpenERP packages. Looking more, I see that not only does it incorporate three projects (the server, addons, and the web module), but it also installs an init.d script, creates a user, and some other stuff. I'm starting to wonder if for whatever reason, OpenERP SA wants to keep their packaging methods secret.